# ReactJS: Button Enable disable with change color

Tags: reactjs

here I have a problem related to making the disable and enable button logic functions.

**So, when the user selects the menu in the select option, the button that was originally disabled becomes enable and the color of the button changes too.**

*how to create such a function? Thanks.*

before choosing, the button is disabled.
[image]

User selects menu.

[image]

The user after selecting the menu, the button changes to enable and the button color also changes.

[image]

My Code =

```
const ButtonModal = () => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  const handleModal = () => setOpenModal(!openModal);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={handleModal}
        className="bg-merah text-white font-bold text-sm rounded-2xl w-48 h-10 py-2 mb-6"
      >
        Perbarui Kompetitor
      </button>
      <Modal
        center
        open={openModal}
        onClose={handleModal}
        showCloseIcon={false}
      >
        <section className="grid justify-items-end">
          <AiOutlineClose
            size={20}
            onClick={handleModal}
            className="cursor-pointer"
          />
        </section>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center mb-4">
          <section className="inline-flex gap-2">
            <p className="font-bold text-center">Pembaruan Data Kompetitor</p>
          </section>
        </div>
        <p>
          Tambah data dengan memilih nama kompetitor yang tersedia atau masukkan
          data baru.
        </p>
        <p className="font-bold mt-6">Nama Kompetitor</p>
        <div class="flex justify-center">
          <div class="mb-3 w-600 mr-6 mt-2">
            <select
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)}
              class="form-select appearance-none
      block
      w-full
      px-3
      py-1.5
      mb-1
      text-base
      font-normal
      text-gray-700
      bg-white bg-clip-padding bg-no-repeat
      border border-solid border-gray-300
      rounded
      transition
      ease-in-out
      m-0
      focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
              aria-label="Default select example"
            >
              <option selected>Pilih nama kompetitor</option>
              <option value="biznet">Biznet</option>
              <option value="cbn">CBN</option>
              <option value="first_media">First Media</option>
              <option value="iconet">Iconet</option>
              <option value="oxygen">Oxygen</option>
              <option value="my_republik">My Republik</option>
              <option value="other">Lainnya</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        {selectedOption === "other" && (
          <div class="mb-6">
            <input
              class="w-[37.5rem] bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
              placeholder="Masukan nama kompetitor..."
              required
            />
          </div>
        )}

        <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
          <button
            onClick={handleModal}
            type="button"
            class="inline-block px-6 py-2 border-2 border-red-600 text-red-600 font-medium text-xs leading-tight rounded hover:bg-black hover:bg-opacity-5 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
          >
            Kembali
          </button>
          
          <button
            type="button"
            class="inline-block ml-6 px-6 py-2.5 bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 font-medium text-xs leading-tight rounded shadow-md hover:bg-gray-300 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-gray-300 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-gray-400 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
            disabled
          >
            Lanjutkan
          </button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the button's `disabled` attribute to the `selectedOption` state - is this what you're after?

And do the same for changing colour, using a ternary to set the value.

```
<button
  onClick={handleModal}
  disabled={!selectedOption}
  style={{ background: selectedOption ? 'red': 'transparent' }}
  className="bg-merah text-white font-bold text-sm rounded-2xl w-48 h-10 py-2 mb-6"
/>
```

EDIT: I think I saw you mention in a comment that it's the other button. Just set them on the other button then.
Also edited to bind to the more appropriate state `selectedOption`.

```
disabled={!selectedOption}
style={{ background: selectedOption ? 'red': 'transparent' }}
```

Comment: yes realised it's probably having selected an option `selectedOption` that's the more appropriate one to bind it to - I just mistook that state because that's the only one being handled.